# User defined type for unsigned 64-bit value vs NUMERIC(20,0)

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Let's say I want to create a table that has some columns which I want to contain 64-bit unsigned integers. I can go about this several different ways, some of which may not be valid or have consequences:

1. Use `NUMERIC(20,0)` and add a check constraint that makes sure that the value is not negative and is within the bounds of a 64-bit unsigned integer (i.e., >=0 and <18,446,744,073,709,551,616). Furthermore, the logic of the check constraint can be encapsulated in a UDF so as to avoid redundancy.
2. Create a CLR User Defined Type that encapsulates this logic (and ultimately wraps a System.UInt64). Use the type for both column types and Stored Procedure parameters. Would such a type give me greater capability (e.g., by preventing invalid values from being passed into a stored proc at the call site)?
3. Reuse the BCL System.UInt64 type. Would this even be possible?

I am looking for someone who is knowledgeable in the capabilities/integration of SQLCLR to assess my ideas, above and comment on the best course of action.

Thanks

Comment: Do you expect values > 2^63-1? Or just don't want values < 0?

Comment: I definitely need to support values > 2**63-1

Comment: I don't know why someone voted this question down. It is a reasonable question.

Answer (score 1):

Use numeric(20,0) and a check constraint to restrict `0 <= x <= 18446744073709551615` (fixed on edit)

SQL Server does not have unsigned 64 but integer so you'd have to do some logic in the client to make it appear int not decimal

The upper check limit is needed because 19E18 is more then unsigned 64 but OK for numeric(20,0). This may not be desirable if the DB values overflows and breaks in the client.

And if you decide that you need an extra few zeros you can change to `numeric (23, 0)` or higher...

Comment: What about 10,000,000,000,000,000,000? This won't go into bigint `SELECT CAST(10000000000000000000 AS bigint)`. This works `SELECT CAST(10000000000000000000 AS decimal(20,0))` and is less then 2^64-1 (unsigned 64 bit limit)

Comment: true, I left out a digit before that is why it had no problem..Numeric is the way to go

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, which is whether a SQLCLR type would work better...

Comment: @Michael Goldshteyn: no, it wouldn't. SQLCLR adds complexity for something that be managed with native SQL Server data types. It adds no value. In my shop we cannot use SQLCLR too; this may not apply but it may affect you later. It isn't worth discussing to be honest when it can be achieved without CLR.

Comment: It cannot be achieved efficiently using SQL native types. A numeric(20,0) type is far less efficient than a 64-bit unsigned integer for comparisons, computation, indexing and space. Whether a custom CLR type will add enough overhead to a 64-bit unsigned native int so as to make it a bad choice along with other potential pitfalls, is the nature of my question. We have CLR turned on, so that is a non-issue. In any event, SQL Server already uses CLR internally for hierarchyid and the geospatial types, whether CLR is turned on or not, so I would not categorize my question as overly ridiculous.

Comment: @Michael Goldshteyn: There is no SQL Server unsigned 64 bit so it's moot about using that. Numeric (20,0) (which is native) will be more efficient then CLR because it's still a number to sort on etc. Do you want someone to agree to SQLCLR, or someone to offer what will be more efficient? If you think you can do a CLR type more efficiently then numeric, then do so. And whether hierarchyid or geospatial are CLR is irrelevant to storing numbers

Comment: I am looking for someone to comment on what is more efficient. SQLCLR is already enabled.

Comment: @Michael Goldshteyn: I've told you what is more efficient. Whatever. Edit: I voted the question down.

Comment: I am not looking for an answer based on feelings or the fact that your DBA will not let you use SQLCLR. I am looking for an objective answer.

Comment: @Michael Goldshteyn: Jolly good. You haven't had any other answers yet. Have you looked my rep and badges and the tags I answer...? Try a bounty to see if someone agrees to CLR

Comment: I hate to break it to you, but your distaste for CLR does not change the fact that CLR code in SQL Server that does not touch DB data (i.e., non-relational tasks) runs leaps and bounds faster as compared to T-SQL code performing the same functionality. This has been demonstrated time and again. From a time performance perspecitve, T-SQL is only good for one thing and it is relational access to data in the DB (i.e., the SQL in T-SQL).

Comment: @Michael Goldshteyn: ha ha ha. I have no problems with CLR if suits the task at hand: complex datatypes, custom aggrgegates, etc. For a simple scalar datatype your analogy fails because a CLR datatype will be used in a *table* and thus take longer to compare then a native datatype *per row*. Still no more answers...

Comment: And you know this because you've measured it, I'm sure. There is nothing like performance assumptions pulled out of thin air.